# Android - Download Manager WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, canvas, webview

I'm working on a project that i have a Javascript Page where i do a Canvas and download this canvas as a PNG image.

It's working pretty well, on the web browser and on the mobile browser.

BUT, i want to display this Js page in a WebView on my Android App. The problem is that the download is not working on  the webview.

I've already tried a bunch of diferent options, like Download Manager and Download Listnner.

I want my app be able to download the canvas as a PNG on the App's WebView.

Hope someone help! Thanks! ;)

MY Js Canvas Code:

```
function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL('image/png');
link.download = filename;}

document.getElementById('btn-download').addEventListener('click', function() {
downloadCanvas(this, 'canvas', "myCanvasImage.png");
}, false);
```

Here is my Adroid Code:

```
WebView mapview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.map_view1);
        mapview1.loadUrl("http://www.myjscanvas.com/download");
        WebSettings webSettings = mapview1.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.getAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs ();

        mapview1.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```